# What sorting algorithm does qt QTableWidget::sortItems() use?

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qtablewidget

I can't find information about it anywhere, so I hope I can get help with it here.
I use `void QTableWidget::sortItems(int column, Qt::SortOrder order = Qt::AscendingOrder)` function to sort data in my tablewidget by time (which is represented in one of the columns) and I wonder what algorithm is used here to sort my items.

Comment: *I can't find information about it anywhere* -- Doesn't Qt come with complete source code?

Comment: See https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qtablewidget.cpp#n477

Comment: stable_sort, which typically is merge_sort. You get O(n log(n)) complexity